# Replace space in between double quote to underscore

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace a space to underscore, if the space is in between double quotes. Example:

```
given    = 'hello "welcome to" python "blog"'
expected = 'hello "welcome_to" python "blog"'
```

My actual string is in SQL code and I need to transform it to use underscore for migration purpose.

#### What I tried

```py
import re

s = 'hello "welcome to" java 2 "blog"'
a = re.sub('(\"[\w\s]+\")', '_', s)
print (a)
```

Also been trying and trying to google but can't find yet.

How to do in Python?

Comment: What do you get as result when running your code? What makes you think, the regex should fit? Did you test the regex online, e.g. [regex101: build, test, and debug regex](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: **Assuming** that your text does not contain "special characters" and that whitespace doesn't have to be strictly respected (i.e. it would be okay to trasform a tab into a space, or multiple spaces into a single space), a simple & dirty way of doing this *could* be using the [`shlex` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to `split` the text into tokens, then map the tokens by replacing the spaces and adding double quotes in tokens that had a space and finally use `' '.join(tokens)` to re-join them together.

Comment: Some (migration) context might help to find a solution-fit: What happens with this _underscore-phrases_ afterwards, are they extracted or should the surrounding text remain? Put it other: How does it make the migration easier when underscores, and not spaces?

Comment: Given input as `'hello "welcome to the   world" java 2 "blog "'`, would you expect `'hello "welcome_to_the___world" java 2 "blog_"'` ? Or should there be any further cleaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't forced to use regex, don't, because that's not a good option here.

```py
inp = 'hello "welcome to" python "blog"'
data = inp.split('"')
for i, part in enumerate(data[:-1]):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        data[i] = part.replace(' ', '_')
out = '"'.join(data)
print(out)
```

```py
'hello "welcome_to" python "blog"'
```

You can do this with a list comprehension if you want, but it looks worse imo

```py
'"'.join(s if i % 2 == 0 else s.replace(' ', '_') for i, s in enumerate(inp.split('"')))
```

or formatted

```py
'"'.join(
    s if i % 2 == 0
    else s.replace(' ', '_')
    for i, s in enumerate(inp.split('"')[:-1])
)
```

Comment: `if i %2 == 1` should be `if i % 2 == 1 and i < len(data) - 1` to avoid the case of single double quote in the string. Or `enumerate(data[:-1])`. e.g. `inp = 'hello "welcome to python blog'`

Comment: @Jay right. Since this is for SQL code the quotes are guaranteed to be balanced though, except in the case of escaped quotes, which it doesn't sound like OP is looking for.

Comment: @Jay You can just add add a `if inp.count('"') % 2 != 0: raise ValueError('Unbalanced quotes')`. IMHO it's not clear how you'd want to handle unbalanced quotes, so it makes more sense to just throw up. [*In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), since it's not clear how to handle that case... don't.

Comment: This seems to work for small query now @samathingamajig :-) 

Will test it more when I have more complex queries. but I think i got an idea now. I totally focus too much using regex which I think you're right that is not a viable .solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can use the loop for iterate your string and generate new string with the char of source string (change it when you found space between double quotes). But the bad side of my solution is a creating a new string every iteration.

```
given = 'hello "welcome to" python "blog"'
double_quote = False
expected = ''
for c in given:
    if double_quote:
        if c == ' ':
            c = '_'
        elif c == '"':
            double_quote = False
    elif c == '"':
            double_quote = True
    expected += c
print(expected)
```

Maybe we can optimize my code within a list

```
given = 'hello "welcome to" python "blog"'
double_quote = False
expected = []
for c in given:
    if double_quote:
        if c == ' ':
            c = '_'
        elif c == '"':
            double_quote = False
    elif c == '"':
        double_quote = True
    expected.append(c)
expected = ''.join(expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to replace spaces with underscores within double quotes using `re.sub()`:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\"[^\"]+\"')

def repl(m):
    return m[0].replace(' ', '_')

inp = 'hello "welcome to" python "blog"'
out = re.sub(pat, repl, inp)
print(out)
```

The regular expression will match

- a double quote `\"`, followed by
- anything that isn't a double quote `[^\"]+`, followed by
- another double quote `\"`

Then the replacement logic is in the `repl()` function, which just takes the first match of the group and replaces all the spaces with underscores.

As long as the parentheses are balanced, this will work. From Python's [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern.

@Samathingamajig's solution is excellent, and probably a bit faster, but here's this option in case you're wanting to do it with regex (or see an example of how it might be done).

Comment: Thanks Kimbo for the alternate solution. I'll try also tomorrow when working :-) 
I'd try anything possible and as simple as possible for my fellow colleagues that do not know python much. (They're all SQLers only. LoL)